# What's "feel universal" mean?

Tags: meaning

my Chinese subtitle of feel universal is author makes you feel the same. I wish to get some explanation. Thanks.

A: How was the book?

B: You know, the translation is a little stilted, but he is amazing.
The book is about his life, but he makes every detail `feel universal`.

C: I'll finish it tonight.

Comment: The book written in a way that anyone who read can perceive the author's feeling or put himself instead of the author (readers' identification with the book)

Comment: The verb 'feel' applies to the reader not to the detail. 'Makes every detail feel universal (to the reader).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means he's making every detail applicable to everyone (*everyone* being the readers).

> **universal** (*adj.*)
> Of, affecting, or done by all people or things in the world...
> *It is rooted in a specific place and culture, but the concerns are universal.*
>
> <sub>[Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/universal)</sub>

The quote you provided contrasts *his life* with *universal*—the former having a very restricted scope and the latter having a very big scope (or *universal* scope).